# Analytic continuation of $\frac{\log(1-z^2)}{z^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to find the largest open set where I can analytically continue  $\frac{\log(1-z^2)}{z^2}$.

**Attempt**
The numerator is analytic in $\mathbb{C}\setminus[-\infty,-1]\cup[1,\infty]$ (by linking the branch points $\pm 1$ and $\infty$)and the denumerator non-zero outside zero, so by intersecting:

$$U=\mathbb{C}\setminus[-\infty,-1]\cup[1,\infty].$$

However, taking them together I think there is a larger set i.e.: $\mathbb{C}\setminus [-1,1]$

How to show that $\infty$ is not a branch point for $\dfrac{\log(1-z^2)}{z^2}$? Any hints.

As $z\to \infty$ we set $\frac{1}{z}$ and take $z\to 0$ then:

$$r^{2}e^{i2\theta}(log(z-1)+log(z+1)-2log(z))$$

so by making a small circle around 0, the first two terms are fixed but the last one is shifted. So infinity is actually a branch point.

Any mistakes?

Comment: Why don't you think you can continue to $z = 1/2$?  I can certainly center a disk at $1/2 + \mathrm{i} \epsilon$...

Comment: It depends on where you put the branch cut. I choose to put it in [-1,1].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To analyze behaviour at $\infty$, set $z = 1/\zeta$.  Then you are studying the neighborhood of $0$ of \begin{align*}
    \zeta^2 \log(1-\zeta^{-2}) &= \zeta^2 \log(\zeta^{-2}(\zeta^{2}-1)) \\
        &= \zeta^2 \left( \log(\zeta + 1) + \log(\zeta - 1) - 2 \log(\zeta) \right) \text{.}
\end{align*}  Put a small loop around $0$.  The $\zeta^2$, $\log(\zeta + 1)$, and $\log(\zeta - 1)$ do not cause any branch difficulties.  However, $-2 \log(\zeta)$ moves by $-4\pi \mathrm{i}$, so $\infty$ is a branch point and there is a branch cut terminating at $\infty$.  (It's other end is one of the other two branch points or is a point on your cut, $[-1,1]$.)

Page 11 [here](http://math.mit.edu/classes/18.305/Notes/n00Branch_Points_B_Cuts.pdf) has much nicer diagrams than I can make.  (The document is Dr. R. Rosales's *Branch Points and Branch Cuts (18.04, MIT)*, from 11 October 1999.)

In slightly more detail, $\oint -2 \zeta^2 \log \zeta \,\mathrm{d}\zeta$ where the path is a small circle of radius $r \in (0,1)$ centered at $0$ is $\frac{4\pi\mathrm{i}}{3} \mathrm{e}^{3r} \rightarrow \frac{4\pi\mathrm{i}}{3}$ as $r \rightarrow 0$, so $\zeta = 0$ is a branch point.  Therefore $z = \infty$ is a branch point.  (I did that integral "by memory" and I don't recall if I've dropped a minus sign.  Either way, you get a branch point.)